How to redo this plumbing for one sided sink
It looks like both drains go into the wall and are attached with black tubing. We’re moving from a dual sided sink to a one sided. How can we do this? 


@crip659 thank you so much! Is there a certain cap we should be looking for?

Welcome. Please take the [tour], which will explain why @crip659 has not provided a proper answer. You can expect one or more below to which you'll need to respond.

It's a bit odd that there are two drain stubs in this situation. Normally a dual sink is brought together before a single trap. That means, unless there's more to this than is apparent, you can simplify by capping one.
To determine which to cap, consider your final sink connection height. If you can make the upper drain work with proper slope, you gain storage space down low. Otherwise cap the upper one.
Do this either by removing the threaded components of the sink trap and installing a threaded cap with sealing tape or compound, or by cutting the threaded trap adapter off and cementing on a cap.
